# Python reading certain values from a csv file into a list

Tags: python, list, csv, nested

I am having some trouble reading specific data from a csv file into a list in Python. Below is an example of my csv file:

```
Round 1
Player1  Score  Player2  Score
P1       5      P2       3
P3       2      P4       4
Round 2
Player1  Score  Player2  Score
P1       3      P4       6
Round 3...
```

(The cells are merged across the top for Round 1 and Round 2)

I am able to append all of the data in this csv file into a list however, I am wanting to ignore the row that contain "Round 1" and the row below it that contains "Player1", "Score" etc and just append the data. The same goes for the "Round 2" row and the row below. The desired list will look something like: [[P1, 5, P2, 3][P3, 2, P4, 4][P1, 3, P4, 6]]. Below is an example of my code:

```
playerScores = []
with open(scoreFile) as scores
    for row in csv.reader(scores)
        playerScores.append(row)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am struggling (PS I tried to use "next(scoreFile)" however, it only got rid of the header "Round 1" for me)

Cheers,

Comment: Skip appending the row if  the value of `row[0]` starts with `Round` or `Player`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simple `if` condition?

```
playerScores = []
with open(scoreFile) as scores
    for row in csv.reader(scores):
        if row and not row[0].startswith('Round') and not row[0].startswith('Player'):
            playerScores.append(row)
```

Comment: Perfect mate works like a charm! Appreciate the help :D

Comment: Quick side question, is there a way I could skip "Round 1" scores and just start appending scores from "Round 2"?

Comment: Sure, see the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

**To start from Round 2**

either you can add a new flag `later_rounds`:

```
playerScores = []
later_rounds = False
with open(scoreFile) as scores:
    for row in csv.reader(scores):
        if row and row[0].startswith('Round 2'):
            later_rounds = True 
        if later_rounds and row and not row[0].startswith('Round') and not row[0].startswith('Player'):
            playerScores.append(row)
```

Or you can skip the beginning in another loop:

```
playerScores = []
with open(scoreFile) as scores:
    scoreReader = csv.reader(scores)
    for row in scoreReader:
        if row and row[0].startswith('Round 2'):
            break
    for row in scoreReader:
        if row and not row[0].startswith('Round') and not row[0].startswith('Player'):
            playerScores.append(row)
```